# Like a facebook page via Facebook SDK for PHP

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am posting a link to the facebook-timeline of a user via the Facebook SDK for PHP.

```
$example_link = "https://www.facebook.com/pages/Mark-Zuckerberg/112432568767916?fref=ts&rf=112845672063384";
$example_text = "Hello World";
$response = (new FacebookRequest(
//Post a message and a link to the users timeline
$session, 'POST', '/me/feed', array(
        'link' => $example_link,
        'message' => $example_text
                      )
                    ))->execute()->getGraphObject();
```

This example writes a text to a users timeline "Hello World" with a link to Mark Zuckerbergs Facebook page.

My Question is:
Is it possible, that I not only post a link to a valid facebook page (e.g Mark Zuckerberg), but also like it in the same step?

Comment: No, Facebook pages can not be liked via API. (And please also be aware, that the message part of such a post must be generated by the user, i.e. typed in by them – you are not allowed to specify the message for them.)

Comment: The message part in above example works. The user does not have to write an own message. (It says "Hello World" like it should). But of course I have to ask the user first for permission to do so. (scope = 'publish_actions')

Comment: If the message says "Hello World", then "Hello World" _must_ have been typed in by the user. The user _has_ to write their own message, or your app is not allowed to post a message at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not in one step. You have to use the `$response->id` to like the created post with `/{post_id}/likes`.

```
$example_link = "https://www.facebook.com/pages/Mark-Zuckerberg/112432568767916?fref=ts&rf=112845672063384";
$example_text = "Hello World";
$response = (new FacebookRequest(
    //Post a message and a link to the users timeline
    $session, 'POST', '/me/feed', array(
        'link' => $example_link,
        'message' => $example_text
        )
    ))->execute()->getGraphObject();

$responseLike = (new FacebookRequest(
    //Post a message and a link to the users timeline
    $session, 'POST', '/'. $response->id . '/likes'
```

See

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.3/user/feed#publish
- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.3/object/likes#publish

Comment: Hi! Thank you for your answer. Unfortunately I have expressed myself wrong. I do not want to like the Post that I just made, but I want to like the facebook page itself. In the example: I want to like the Mark Zuckerberg fanpage. Is this possibile without adding an extra like-button? (Thats what I meant with "same step"). - My Bad

Comment: You cannot like a page via the API

Comment: Oh, that's a pity... But Thank You!